# count check boxes in asp.net table

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am very much new to asp and java:
i have designed a page with a table and some checkboxes inside that table i want to set a condition using script to alert user not to check more than four checkboxes. Or if user checks four checkboxes the other remaining checkboxes available in this table must get disabled and if the user unchecks any of the selected checkboxes all the disabled shall get enabled back for new selection. There are some check boxes which belong to same group (cell) which if user clicks one of them the other selected checkboxes in that group(cell) must get unchecked just like toggle in nutshell only one checkbiox must get selected in that cell.I have done that in java but dont know how to have check on the checkboxes more than four. 
(P.S) In (group I)  of the table checkbox GE is cheked and disabled this check box is mandatory among four checkbox it should be always checked

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChkValidate() {
        var counter = 0;


        var panel = document.getElementById ("panel1")
        for (i = 0; i < panel.children.length; i++) {
            if (panel.children[i].type == 'checkbox')
            {
                if (panel.children[i].checked == true) {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }
            }
            if (counter > 4)

            {
                alert('You have reached to maximum selection');
                return false;

            }
        }
    }
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">

     function aspcheckED0() {
         document.getElementById("PS0").checked = false;
     }
     function aspcheckPS0() {
         document.getElementById("ED0").checked = false;

     }

    function aspcheckEL0() {
        document.getElementById("HS0").checked = false;
        document.getElementById("MA0").checked = false;
     }
     function aspcheckHS0() {
         document.getElementById("EL0").checked = false;
         document.getElementById("MA0").checked = false;
     }
     function aspcheckMA0() {
         document.getElementById("EL0").checked = false;
         document.getElementById("HS0").checked = false;
     }

     function aspcheckUR0() {
         document.getElementById("PJ0").checked = false;
     }
     function aspcheckPJ0() {
         document.getElementById("UR0").checked = false;
     }
     function aspcheckAR0() {
         document.getElementById("PR0").checked = false;
     }
     function aspcheckPR0() {
         document.getElementById("AR0").checked = false;
     }

    </script>



        <table id="artstable" align="center" class="auto-style53" style="border: thin dotted #6666FF; font-family: Verdana;
        border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #E6E6E6;">
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="auto-style188" colspan="10"><strong>Enter Your Admission Details</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="auto-style42" colspan="5">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong> Select Your Course:</strong></td>
                <td align="right" class="auto-style42" colspan="5">
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbcourse" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="54px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" style="text-align: left; font-weight: 700;" Width="385px">
                        <asp:ListItem>BA</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSC</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSCN</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BCOM</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="auto-style140" style="border: thin dotted #0000FF"><strong>B.A</strong></td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style113" colspan="0">Group&nbsp; 1</td>
                <td class="auto-style162">Group&nbsp; 2</td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style114">Group 3</td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style95">Group 4</td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style150">Group 5</td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style174">Group 6</td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style160">Group 7</td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style136">Group 8</td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style116">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="auto-style140" style="border: thin dotted #0000FF"><span class="auto-style43">Select Any four </span>
                    <br class="auto-style43" />
                    <span class="auto-style43">subjects ,Max one from<br /> each group</span></td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style117">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="ge" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="GE"   onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch" />
                    <br />
                </td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style163" rowspan="1">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="PS" runat="server"  BackColor="#CCFFFF" Text="PS"  onclick="aspcheckPS();" SkinID="ch"/>
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="ED" runat="server"  BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="ED"  onclick="aspcheckED();" SkinID="ch"  />
                </td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style118">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="ec" runat="server"  BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="EC"  onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style96">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="kr" runat="server"  BackColor="#CCFFFF"   Text="KR" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch" />
                    <br />
                </td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style151" rowspan="1">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="MA" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="MA"  onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch" />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="EL" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="EL"  onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch"/>
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="HS" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="HS"  onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch"/>
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                </td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style175" rowspan="1">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="UR" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="UR"  onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch"  />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="PJ" runat="server"  BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="PJ" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch"  />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                </td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style161" rowspan="1">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="AR" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="AR"  onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch"  />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="PR" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="PR" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch"  />
                </td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style137">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="fe" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="FE"  onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch"  />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Table? Table row?  What table and row?

Comment: i have just edited the question plz have another look

Comment: @SteveWellens just updated the query plz have another link